# Mongoose query on specific property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that contains `trial_ends` and I want to find all documents where that field is exactly 10 days from now.

What I am struggling is in how to query the model using that exact property.

My code so far:

```
const TEN_DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10;

const orgs = await OrganizationColl.find(
        {
            trial_ends: (e) =>  // GET THE DATES THAT MATCHE TEN_DAYS - trial_ends
        }
    )

    console.log(orgs)
```

Comment: You want it to match excatly in milisecond or just want it to be in that day?

Comment: Just that day !!

Comment: what's is the type of `trial_ends`?